# Describe the pod info

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How I can describe the pod information if that is not belongs to default namespace. With default namespace I do not have any issue.

But I wanted to have information for that specific pod which does have namespace align to it.

[image]

But when I wanted to describe the same pod I could able to make that, see
[image]

I tried with all namespace flag but it does not allow me to query, like this.

`kubectl describe  pods airflow-scheduler-646ffbfd67-k7dgh --all-namespaces`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to explicitly mention the namespace of the pod which you plan to describe. For that, you need to use the `-n` flag to kubectl command:

```
kubectl describe  pods airflow-scheduler-646ffbfd67-k7dgh -n <namespace>
```

If you are using `bash` environment to connect to Kubernetes cluster, you can use the below function to describe the POD from any namespace, you may alias it or put it in your bashrc:

```
describe_pod()
{
if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
    echo "Error: Pod name is missing as input argument"
    return 1
fi

pod_name=${1}

kubectl describe pod "${pod_name}"  -n $(kubectl get pod -A | awk -v pod="$pod_name" -v def=default '$2==pod{ns=$1} END{if(!length(ns))print def; else print ns}')
}
```

Example usage:

```
describe_pod <pod-name-from-any-namespace>
```

Eg:

```
describe_pod airflow-scheduler-646ffbfd67-k7dgh
```

With a simple modification of this function, it can be used for other k8s objects.